# Trying to call a class method from a protocol (Swift)

Tags: swift, testing, mocking, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to write a fake for `MFMailComposeViewController` for testing so I made a protocol called `MailComposeViewController` and a class `FakeComposeViewController` that is conformed to this protocol. I also made `MFMailComposeViewController` conform to this protocol as well.

So in my code when I call it I am saying of type `MailComposeViewController` I want to have a replacement for `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`. If I try to replace with my protocol using: `MailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` I get the error `Static member 'canSendMail' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'MailComposeViewController.Protocol'` which makes sense. but how would I go about writing around this so I could decide to pass in a FakeComposeViewController.canSendMail() `true` response when testing and the real MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() when running?

Answer (score 2):

You can work with **`Type`** of `MailComposeViewController` itself

```
func check(for viewControllerType: MailComposeViewController.Type) {
    if viewControllerType.canSendMail() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Robert suggested you could also get the type of the passed controller via:

```
func test(controller: MailComposeViewController) {
    if type(of: controller).canSendMail() {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        // Do something different
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution has the advantage of actually passing the controller directly, which then makes it accessible should you need to perform further work with it